# Facebook SSO with Portal Users

Tags: force.com, oauth2, customer-portal, single-sign-on, facebook

I am using Facebook as Auth Provider to allow portal users to login into portal org via their facebook credentials. I have successfully implemented that.

Now, in Registration Handler, while creating user record, I want to get additional information of facebook user like location, phone etc. For this, I have searched and found that force.com has provided a Facebook toolkit which can full-fill my requirements.

I just want to use facebook toolkit in Registration Handler but able to find anyone for this implementation. Can anyone please provide some help on how to use facebook toolkit in registration handler ?